# Get a Table from XML in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, xml

Have a look at the following XML data:

```
<data>
    <test color="red">Red text</test>
    <test color="green">green</test>
</data>
```

Let's say I have several xml-documents with this structure in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE xmldata (
    id bigserial not null,
    documents xml)
```

Now I want to select all possible colors:

```
SELECT id, xpath('//test', xml) FROM xmldata;
```

But this returns a table with the id of each document and a text-array of the test-nodes. Furthermore, documents without any "test" node exist in the result as well - with an empty array {}

What I really want is a table like this:

```
| id | node                              |
|  1 | <test color="red">Red text</test> |
|  1 | <test color="green">green</test>  |
```

What is the syntax I have to use?

I heard that xpath_table may be the function to use - but this function is marked as deprecated...

(The returned table has to have one line for each occurence of the node I searched for. The node itself maybe an xml-snippet, text or something else - isn't really important)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using `xpath_table()`.

Even though some of the functions in the [xml2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xml2.html) extension have been replaced with in-core functions, xpath_table is not one of them (I think this will happen for Postgres 10).

Until then, `xpath_table()` seems to be your only option:

```
SELECT * 
FROM xpath_table('id',
            'documents',
            'xmldata',
            '//test',
            'true') AS t(doc_id integer, data text);
```

Returns:

```
doc_id | data    
-------+---------
     1 | Red text
     1 | green
```

---

In order for this to work you first need to create the extension (as a superuser):

```
create extension xml2;
```

Otherwise the function isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

You have yet another alternative, using **regexp_matches**:

```
 WITH s0 AS
 (
     -- Your original query
     SELECT 
         id, xpath('//test', documents) AS x
     FROM 
         xmldata
 )
 , s1 AS
 (
     -- We unnest the array (convert it to rows)
     SELECT
         id, unnest(x) AS xml_node
     FROM
         s0
 )
 SELECT
     id, 
     xml_node, 
     (regexp_matches(xml_node::text, '<test[^>]*>(.*)<\/test>'))[1] AS data
 FROM
     s1 ;
```

```
 id | xml_node                          | data

 -: | :-------------------------------- | :-------
  1 | <test color="red">Red text</test> | Red text
  1 | <test color="green">green</test>  | green
```

... and you can have everything in just one SELECT

```
 -- Compacted version
 SELECT 
     id, (regexp_matches(unnest(xpath('//test', documents))::text, '<test[^>]*>(.*)<\/test>'))[1] AS xml_node
 FROM 
     xmldata
```

```
 id | xml_node
 -: | :-------
  1 | Red text
  1 | green
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=46996b31e0b6e5a413d1e474ae4faabd)*